css scroll / horizontal scroll not working
The division element area is not able to scroll. I try to use a division with a width of 150px and inside the div is with inline-block elements.
What I need is to able to scroll the div and the inside inline-block appears in a single line.


span {
  display: inline-block;
}

div {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  overflow-x: s croll !important;
}
<p>Display a list of links as a horizontal menu:</p>

<div>123

  <span><a href="/html/default.html" target="_blank">HTML</a></span>
  <span><a href="/css/default.html" target="_blank">CSS</a></span>
  <span><a href="/js/default.html" target="_blank">JavaScript</a></span>

</div>




You have a typo: s croll

is that what you want ?


div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 70px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
<p>Display a list of links as a horizontal menu:</p>

<div>

  <span><a href="/html/default.html" target="_blank">HTML</a></span>
  <span><a href="/css/default.html" target="_blank">CSS</a></span>
  <span><a href="/js/default.html" target="_blank">JavaScript</a></span>

</div>




Questions should include an explanation, not a question. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].
